# .NET equivalent of Java Servlet Filters

Tags: java, .net, servlet-filters

Is there a .NET equivalent to using Servlet Filters for request pre-processing in .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an HttpModule and handle the `HttpApplication` events (Probably `BeginRequest`).

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC provides just such a filter API, along with a set of out-of-the-box filters for validation, authorization, and other common pre- or post-processing needs.  Here is an introductory tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs